# Addition of two double type variables returns very long decimal values

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I have an application where I intend to add two double type values. In some certain situation, the result contains a very long decimal part. I was able to reproduce the problem in a separate program.

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main (String args []) {
        double total1= 8.69;
        double total2 = 1.69;
        double totalamount = total1 + total2 ;

        System.out.println(totalamount);
    }
}
```

**Output: 10.379999160766602** (The expexted output should be in the format of #.##)

I have tried changing the values of `total1` and `total2`. The output is in expected format in some cases. The occurrence of the long values is very random and it goes with the `float` datatype as well.

What is the explanation for the above behavior?

Comment: must read good source about floating point numbers. Hint : there is no exactly  8.69 or 1,69 too

Comment: `doubles` are stored as bytes and they don't have exact representation thus when you do operations on them you can get not exact result, try using `BigDecimal` to get exact result

Comment: @Satya and YMomb question is about nature, not formatting

Comment: If that's the actual output you're getting from that code, then something's very wrong. But I suspect that it's not: I suspect you were using `float` rather than `double` in at least one place (either that, or `float` literals like `8.69f`). Please show code and results that match.